# why are my cloth objects not acting properly

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]

my cloth objects were fine when all of the sudden today they started going crazy halfway through my animation. does anyone know what is happening? also I cant get the cloth to go past 250 frames.
[image]

Comment: could be double vertices or too much stress on the mesh

Comment: @ Asher Heller  Could you share your file with me please so I can take a closer look?  you can upload files through here:https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I investigated this scene, I found that your mesh was not properly baked.  All you need to do is select the waving yellow flags, go to the cloth settings in the physics tab, scroll down, and click on bake.  (see image below)
[image]
After it is done baking, your simulation should work fine.  If you encounter further problems, let me know and I'll be happy to help!  Hope I've been helpful to you! : )

(PS, if this answer worked, please mark it as accepted)